# Need access to funds that were earned & taxed prior to establishing LLC

Tags: united-states, capital-gains-tax, limited-liability-company, sole-proprietorship

In 2020, I worked as a sole proprietor and kept a 'business' account for my earnings.  These were taxed twice - both as personal income and business income.  Beginning 2021, I created an LLC (with me the only employee) mostly for the tax advantage and to provide legal protection for personal assets.

When I setup the bank account for my LLC, the bank asked if I wanted to transfer the monies from my previous sole proprietor business account.  I should've said no, but said yes.  To access these funds now, I believe they need to be considered distributions, and pay capital gains tax.  **Does it matter that 1) these funds were already taxed twice, and 2) were earned prior to becoming an LLC?**

The amount is $80k, and I'd planned to use that for personal expenses.  This was possible as a sole proprietor, but I fear that I can't touch that money unless it's for business expenses, or subject to that capital gains tax.  Feel like I've already set myself up with a major fail right out of the gate.

Comment: Sole proprietors only have personal income and are not taxed twice. Either you were not a sole proprietor in 2020 or you paid taxes that you shouldn't have.

Comment: Thanks for the comment, my wording was probably unclear.  When saying "taxed twice" I'm referring to being taxed on my profits for both income taxes AND the 15% self-employment tax.

Comment: To fix other wording, I'm pretty sure capital gains tax doesn't apply here.

Answer (score 3):

"To access these funds now, I believe they need to be considered distributions, and pay capital gains tax. "

This is likely not the case. When you transferred personal money to the LLC, you should have recorded it as either a loan or some form of capital increase. Taking the money out should be considered a reduction of your assets in the LLC, not a taxable distribution.

**However** you may want to review whatever documentation you have from that point in time to be sure that you can record everything appropriately. As an example - did you intend for it to be a loan, but never charged the LLC interest for the use of your funds? Legal advice may be required to ensure everything is above-board.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't have an accountant already, I highly recommend that you get one to help you with this.

I assume you have or will elect to have your LLC taxed as an S-Corp.  From your comment, it seems that your goal is to reduce self-employment tax and the only way to do that is to elect taxation as an S-corp.

Assuming this is the case, you should be able to undo the transfer of money to your company bank account as explained in the excellent answer by @Grade 'Eh' Bacon.  You'll need an accountant's help to get this right.

You should also note that [Trump created a 20% tax deduction](https://www.investopedia.com/taxes/how-becoming-llc-could-save-taxes-under-trump/) for sole proprietors and LLCs with pass through taxation (i.e., not S-Corp taxation).  If you elect S-Corp taxation you lose this tax deduction.  There is thus less, if any, benefit to electing S-corp taxation with this Trump tax deduction.  Though who knows how long the Trump tax deduction will last...